# Copy a data from wpf datagrid to lotus notes

Tags: c#, wpf, lotus-notes

I am pulling some details from sql server and displaying in data-grid.

I would like to export the data-grid's data to lotus notes.

1.Check the lotus notes is already launched or not.If No,Launch the lotus notes

2.Paste the data-grid data to notes by opening as a new memo.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save you alot of trouble, your answer is basically "No".

You will only get as far as launching Lotus Notes, but inserting a data grid, as a table I presume, is not possible through the current Lotus Notes API's available from C#. Primarily because you will not be able to access the Memo form in the UI. Without more requirements, and on first appearances, this is a bit messy. It sounds like the user has asked for the data to "appear" in an email that they can complete drafting directly in Lotus Notes.

Based on what you have advised so far, you would be better off in C# creating a standard email message with the data, and just email it to the user. Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

What kind of application is the application in the middle? On the left there is SQL-Server, on the right there is Lotus. Either one of those deals with the logic or there is something in the middle.

You mention a memo, does this mean you will be sending an email. And if so, should this email contain the information as a table?